# json_encode not working as expected using array source

Tags: php, json

In my php I am reading a file and successfully getting each row into an array (`$line[1]` because its a 3 column CSV and I just need the 2nd value):

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false)
    {           
        $course[] = array('course' => $line[1]);            
    }
```

`$course[]` correctly contains the array like:

```
0 => 
array (size=1)
  'course' => string 'Course One' (length=68)
1 => 
array (size=1)
  'course' => string 'Course Two' (length=45)
```

Problem is I cannot get the array to convert to json using `json_encode`

```
$json_res = json_encode($course);
```

EDIT: So just to be clear, I have array like this

```
2 => 
array (size=1)
  'course' => string 'Associate Degree of Business Studies' (length=36)
3 => 
array (size=1)
  'course' => string 'Associate Degree of Business Administration' (length=43)
```

`$json_encode` , gives me

```
boolean false
```

Comment: **Note:** You should modify your `while()` loop to not call `fgetcsv()` every single itteration. It could get very resource intensive.

Comment: geez downvoted already, I wonder what I possibly did wrong

Comment: thx @Darren, any example of how to do it better.  Its only a few hundred lines so that's probably why I haven't felt any issues in the past

Comment: @Darren php manual shows similar to what I am doing http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're setting $json_res but checking $json_encode, or is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after taking in consideration all the information you provided, your original code should work. Try this out and let me know if it works.

```
$file = new SplFileObject("file.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$course = array();
foreach ($file as $row) {
    $line = array('course' => $row[1]);
    array_push($course, $line);
}
$json_res = json_encode($course);
var_dump($json_res);
```

**Update:** Try this code and let me know if it works:

```
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$course = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $line = array('course' => utf8_decode($data[1]));
    array_push($course, $line);
}
$json_res = json_encode($course);
var_dump($json_res)
```

;

Comment: the json_encode is still not working, it must be to do with the way CSV rows are coming back - why would one row be returning like this:
string 'Associate Degree of Business Studies' (length=36)
Ie, why the "string" at the start I wonder

Comment: ie, this: `$result = $line[1];
         var_dump($result);` outputs this: `string 'Associate Degree of Business Studies' (length=36)`

Comment: oh I was just guessing that maybe that's why json_encode is not able to do its job ?

Comment: its hard to troubleshoot this because you have lots of lines of data in your csv. Perhaps one of your strings has somthing like an apostrophe thats producing an error.

Comment: ive been trying it in different ways, and it does work for me.

Comment: after your `json_encode`, try running this `var_dump(json_last_error());` let me know what you get

Comment: if the CSV contains rogue quotes, would that break it ?

Comment: youre welcome.. according to the manual this means: JSON_ERROR_UTF8 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: I see what they've done - the CSV contains some double quotes because the string may contain commas that are part of the value, ie, something like "Bachelor of Arts, Science" - removing the quote will make the CSV think there's more fields, so that won't work

Comment: I believe that's fixed it! Thanks very much

Comment: awesome.. No problem buddy. Anytime